# How to sort integer columns in Infragistics WebDataGrid?

Tags: infragistics

I am using Infragistics WebDataGrid. When I try to sort columns having integer data, it sorts data like a string instead of integer. I have already tried adding DataType as System.Int32 but it didn't worked.

`<ig:BoundDataField DataFieldName="BuildingNo" Key="BuildingNo" DataType="System.Int32" DataFormatString="{0:D4}">
<Header Text="Building No" />
</ig:BoundDataField>`

Below is the sorted list which I am getting :

1
10
9
8
7
6
5

Instead of above I should get:
1
5
6
7
8
9
10

Comment: What is the specific version of the assembly containing the WebDataGrid?  Also what are you binding the grid to?

Comment: I did try to reproduce this with NetAdvantage 2013 Volume 1 and didn't reproduce the behavior that you are seeing.  If you have a sample that reproduces the issue, you may want to post it in the WebDataGrid forum for Infragistics to help you with this: http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/196.aspx